# How to output a modified array with a loop in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

For example, I have a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [2, 1, 5, 2]
l2 = [4, 2, 3, 3]

arr_in = np.array([l1,l2])
arr_in
array([[2, 1, 5, 2],
       [4, 2, 3, 3]])
```

I want to do a simple mathematical operation to each of the values (e.g. square and add a constant, x^2 +1 ) and get the following array:

```
arr_out # my modified array
array([[5, 2, 26, 5],
       [17, 5, 10, 10]])
```

It looks like its possible to do so by grouping by the first element of the index -e.g. 0 and 1:

```
for i, value in np.ndenumerate(arr_in):
    dbl = pow(value,2) + 1
    print(i[0],dbl)

0 5
0 2
0 26
0 5
1 17
1 5
1 10
1 10
```

how do I go about it?

Comment: Simply `arr_out = arr_in**2+1`

Comment: As a general rule you want to avoid iteration on a numpy array.  Use, where possible, the methods and operators that can work on the whole array.  That includes power and addition.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#basic-array-operations.  (`x**2+1` does still iterate, but in compiled code which is much faster, and transparent to you, the programmer.)

Answer (score 0):

When working with Numpy arrays, you can make use of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Broadcasting, as the name suggests, *broadcasts* operations over entire arrays. So, if you have array `arr` and do `arr**2`, the exponentiation will be broadcast over the entire array, giving you `arr` but with every element squared. Things work differently when doing something like `arr1 + arr2` depending on the shapes of the arrays, but that is outlined in the linked documentation.

So, for your problem, you can directly apply the operation to `arr_in` to get the desired `arr_out`.

```py
import numpy as np

l1 = [2, 1, 5, 2]
l2 = [4, 2, 3, 3]

arr_in = np.array([l1,l2])
arr_out = arr_in**2 + 1
print(arr_out)
```

Output:

```py
[[ 5  2 26  5]
 [17  5 10 10]]
```

Note that `arr_out` is of type `np.int32`.